# Calculation of transition probabilities of Markov Chain problem

Tags: self-study, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

In the step of learning Markov chains, I came across few questions from assignments on UTDallas website. Finding the transition probabilities seems a bit hard for me in this one particular question only. The question is

(Sec 7.3, page 355, #1) Consider a system with two components. We observe the
state of the system every hour. A given component operating at time $n$ has probability $p$ of failing
before the next observation at time $n + 1$. A component that was in a failed condition at time $n$
has a probability $r$ of being repaired by time $n + 1$, independent of how long the component has
been in a failed state. The component failures and repairs are mutually independent events. Let
$X_n$ be the number of components in operation at time $n$. The process $\{X_n, n = 0, 1, . . .\}$ is a
discrete time homogeneous Markov chain with state space $I = \{0, 1, 2\}$.

a) Determine its transition probability matrix, and draw the state diagram.

b) Obtain the steady state probability vector, if it exists

Although the answers are given, but I cannot understand that on what basis the transition probabilities are calculated.  Can someone help me in this...

I had the following guesses my ownself (which mostly proved to be wrong)

\begin{bmatrix}
    1-r-r^2 & r & r^2\\ 
    ??& ?? & r(1-p) \\
    p^2 & ?? & ??
  \end{bmatrix}

The actual solution that the website pose is following...

\begin{bmatrix}
    (1-r)^2 & 2r(1-r) & r^2\\ p(1-r)& pr + (1-p)(1-r) & r(1-p) \\
    p^2 & 2p(1-p) & (1-p)^2
  \end{bmatrix}

Comment: Thanks Yes it is self-study question. What I am asking is not the solution since I am not taking this exam, I am trying to learn the probability, in general, and markov chains, in specific. Appreciate your comment @Tavrock.

Comment: I am looking if someone can help me to learn HERE how transition probabilities are calculated...Since  to my understanding, transitional probabilities are different than normal probabilities...

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind your guesses? (Also, based on the last comment,  do you know what a transition probability is?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, there are two components and each of them individually could be either in working or failure state. Then the states of the Markov chain be designated as $ff$ both components failed, $wf$ one component working and one component failed, and $ww$ both components working. Given that, the components function independently of each other.

- If the chain is in state $ff$ at time $n$, at the next time point it
  could be in the state

  - $ff$ with probability $(1-r)(1-r)=(1-r)^2$, as the probability of not
    being repaired by next time point is $(1-r)$;
  - $wf$ with probability $2r(1-r)$, as it may be the first component
    that was repaired or the the second component that was repaired, so
    that only one of the two components will be working;
  - $ww$ with probability $r^2$, if both the components got repaired.
- If the chain is in the state $wf$ at time $n$, then at the next time 
  point it could be in the state

  - $ff$ with probability $p(1-r)$, as the working component failed  and 
    the component requiring repair was not yet repaired;
  - $wf$ with probability $pr+(1-p)(1-r)$, as the working component was
    not failed and the component requiring repair is not repaired, so
    that only one component is working, which has a  probability
    $(1-p)(1-r)$; or the component working at the previous time has
    failed and the component requiring repair has got repaired, which has
    a  probability $pr$; mutually exclusiveness of the events results in 
    the required  probability;
  - $ww$ with  probability $r(1-p)$, as the working component does not
    require repair and the failed component got repaired.
- If the chain is in the state $ww$ at time $n$, then at the next time 
  point it could be in the state

  - $ff$ with probability $p^2$, as both components have failed;
  - $wf$ with  probability $2p(1-p)$, which is the sum of probabilities
    of two mutually exclusive events, viz., the first component failed
    and the second working   or the first component working and the
    second component failed;

    - $ww$ with  probability $(1-p)^2$, as both components are still
      working.

Hence, the transition matrix:

\begin{equation*}
P=\begin{array}{c|ccc}
&ff & wf & ww\\
\hline
ff & (1-r)^2& 2r(1-r) & r^2\\
wf & p(1-r) & pr+(1-p)(1-r) & r(1-p) \\
ww & p^2 & 2p(1-p) & (1-p)^2
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thanks.... Helped me a lot in developing understanding and brushing off some dust over my mind